# Checking UIImage Pixel by Pixel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am creating an application in which i am trying to get the color of current touched point, if this point is not black then it will run an iteration/recursion and will store all the non black points in array. I am using this function for Iteration:

```
-(void)function:(CGFloat)positiveX:(CGFloat)positiveY:(CGFloat)negativeX:(CGFloat)negativeY
{
    if (canDoPositiveX == YES)
    {
        //Checking in positive
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX+1 :positiveY :negativeX :negativeY];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoPositiveX = NO;
        }
    }

    if (canDoPositiveY == YES)
    {
        //Checking in positive
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 0"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX :positiveY+1 :negativeX :negativeY];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoPositiveY = NO;
        }
    }

    if (canDoNegativeX == YES)
    {
        //Checking in negative
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX :positiveY :negativeX-1 :negativeY];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoNegativeX = NO;
        }
    }

    if (canDoNegativeY == YES)
    {
        //Checking in negative        
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
        {
            negativeY -= 1;
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX :positiveY :negativeX :negativeY-1];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoNegativeY = NO;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%u",[array count]);

}
```

Now, i am changing the color of those points which are in array, But it only colors straight line of points, not every pixel. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is that the correct syntax for a method? Doesn't seem right to me. You called your function "function"? Not very explicit. What are canDoNegativeY and canDoNegativeX?

Comment: They are just checks (booleans). Furthermore, i have no idea about this type f recursion :P. If you know how to do it well, kindly tell me. @Odrakir
I can give you bounty worth 100 for that.

Comment: I know they are booleans, but I'm afraid I can't help you if I don't understand what your code does. What do those booleans mean?

Comment: @Odrakir Lemme clear it, when the user taps a point on the screen, it will check whether the touched poit is black or white. if it is white the it will perform iteration from that point and will do it until it founds a black pixel....... but the main problem is that this iteration hangs up in the debug session......

Comment: @Odrakir it's something like floodfill.....

Comment: "But it only colors straight line of points" - then maybe your drawing code has a problem?
By the way, turn on XCode warnings - you method signature may not work correctly

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I can't actually test it but it should work.

```
-(void)function:(CGFloat)positiveX:(CGFloat)positiveY:(CGFloat)negativeX:(CGFloat)negativeY
{
    // Check your current point 
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
    {
        // reached the dead end (break recursion)
        return;
    }

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY);
    [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];

    BOOL canDoPositiveX = ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX+1, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"];
    BOOL canDoPositiveY = ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY+1)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"];
    BOOL canDoNegativeX = ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX-1, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"];
    BOOL canDoNegativeY = ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY-1)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"];

    if (canDoPositiveX == YES)
    {
        [self function:positiveX+1 :positiveY :negativeX :negativeY];
    }

    if (canDoPositiveY == YES)
    {
        [self function:positiveX :positiveY+1 :negativeX :negativeY];
    }

    if (canDoNegativeX == YES)
    {
        [self function:positiveX :positiveY :negativeX-1 :negativeY];
    }

    if (canDoNegativeY == YES)
    {
        [self function:positiveX :positiveY :negativeX :negativeY-1];
    }

    NSLog(@"%u",[array count]);
}
```

Also remove these variables from your class canDoPositiveX, canDoPositiveY, canDoNegativeX, canDoNegativeY

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think you didnt get what i want to do. Lemme clear this first. I have a UIImage, when the user taps on the non-black part of UIImage, it should iterate and save all the non-black points of UIImage & as the iteration found the black point it should stop. But this code you gave me is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Check this question:

[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

You should be able to easily use/modify the code on the accepted answer to return only the black (or nearly black) pixels coordinates for a given `UIImage`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this modified code:

```
-(void)function:(CGFloat)positiveX:(CGFloat)positiveY:(CGFloat)negativeX:(CGFloat)negativeY
{
    if (canDoPositiveX == YES)
    {
        //Checking in positive
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX+1 :positiveY :negativeX :negativeY];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoPositiveX = NO;
            canDoPositiveY = YES;
            canDoNegativeX = YES;
            canDoNegativeY = YES;
        }
    }

    if (canDoPositiveY == YES)
    {
        //Checking in positive
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 0"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(positiveX, positiveY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX :positiveY+1 :negativeX :negativeY];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoPositiveX = YES;
            canDoPositiveY = NO;
            canDoNegativeX = YES;
            canDoNegativeY = YES;
        }
    }

    if (canDoNegativeX == YES)
    {
        //Checking in negative
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX :positiveY :negativeX-1 :negativeY];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoPositiveX = YES;
            canDoPositiveY = YES;
            canDoNegativeX = NO;
            canDoNegativeY = YES;
        }
    }

    if (canDoNegativeY == YES)
    {
        //Checking in negative        
        if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self colorOfPoint:CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY)]] isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"])
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(negativeX, negativeY);
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [self function:positiveX :positiveY :negativeX :negativeY-1];
        }
        else
        {
            canDoPositiveX = YES;
            canDoPositiveY = YES;
            canDoNegativeX = YES;
            canDoNegativeY = NO;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%u",[array count]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've already tried this code. But in this code the problem is that it causes stack overflow, like when i tried to call this function, my application paused and then suddenly crashed :(